# Making div scrollable instead of page

Tags: css, css-position, zurb-foundation, positioning

How I can do somthing like that? The question is not about how to write the full code. The question is about how to make such scroll behaviour

[image: Scrolling page]

The upper menu should be fixed. When the menu reaches `div2`, **`div2` starts to scroll**. When `div2` is finished, it resumes to normal interaction.

Comment: Whats the question where is your code?

Comment: I have some knowledge of css&js.

Comment: I don't need full code. if you have idea - paste it and i will try to realize it

Comment: +1 for the handwritten screenshot. We need more of those! I don't know what you're saying though.

Comment: Hello may be this jsfiddle help you
http://jsfiddle.net/wPucQ/

Answer (score 2):

Try doing

```
style="overflow-y: hidden" //at page level

style="overflow-y: scroll" //at main div
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on whether the left and right portions of your diagram are elements, or if that's just the size of the browser beyond the width of your site?

Assuming the latter, in this case it's actually simpler than you're expecting.

You don't need to fix everything and scroll just a `div` element, that would require some JS, which you don't actually need at all in this case.

Instead - just think of it as the page still scrolling as usual, no messing with the scroll interaction, but you fix the menu `div` at the top with `position: fixed;` in CSS.

The other `div` elements *should* automatically scroll behind, but if they don't for some reason due to your actual code, then you can force the menu in front with a `z-index` - it's better to avoid this though, since quickly become hard to maintain or add to.

If you did specifically want to scroll a `div` only - `div1` separately from `div2` say - then you could clunkily solve this with an `iframe` for each. There's no doubt a better JS solution to this, but I'm not JSavvy enough to provide it.